# PHPExcel upload excel sheet to database using header names

Tags: php, excel

I am new to phpexcel so forgive me if this a silly question,
I have a PHP script that takes an excel file and uploads it to my SQL server. it takes data from different columns and inserts it into two different tables. this works fine as long as the columns in the excel sheet stay the same ex: column 1 = name, column 2 = age and so on.

```
     $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
     $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
     $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){

        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE, FALSE);

            $Name = trim($rowData[0][0]);
            $Age = trim($rowData[0][1]);
            $Address = trim($rowData[0][2]);
    }
```

This is in short what I have. as you can see the $name var is always going to take the value from the first column in the file and so on. my issue is that the file I am uploading will not always be in this order. for example, one week the file will have name in column 1 and age in column 2 but next week age will be in column 1 and name in column 2.

The columns have headings that will always match the data in the row so I would like to use the headers like so.

```
     $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
     $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
     $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){

        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL,TRUE, FALSE);

            $Name = trim($rowData[0]['NAME']);
            $Age = trim($rowData[0]['AGE']);
            $Address = trim($rowData[0]['ADDRESS']);

      sql= "insert into dbo.mainTable (NAME,AGE,ADDRESS) VALUES ('$Name','$Age','$Address')";

     $stmt = sqlsrv_query($db,$sql);
    }
```

I think you can do something like this with associative arrays but I just can't work out how to do it with this. I have found some stuff close to what I am asking but when I try any of them it just won't work. if there is a way to do this easily that would be great. This is my last resort as i have searched the internet for nearly a week now so
thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I added a simple query the same way i am doing it now. the reason i am doing it like this is because the full query is a update query and IF rowcount = 0 then insert plus if the rows change at the moment i just have to go to the list above and change the index.

Answer (score -1):

The part of your code that put the data into mysql isn't listed here.
However, mysql has you covered as long as row 1 is contains the headers

```
A    B       C
Name Address Age
```

$header=implode(",",$whatever-row-0-is called

```
$sql="insert into `table` (".$header.") values ('".$col0."','".$col1."','".$col2."'");";
```

It doesn't matter what order the data is in as long as $header is matches.

run 1

```
$header="name,age,address"
```

run 2

```
$header="age,address,name"
```

day3

```
$header="address,age,name"
```

and so on

The database will then automatically put the right data in the right column as long as $header matches the order of the incoming data.

```
$header=join(",", trim($rowData[0]);
```

or

```
$header="'".join("','", trim($rowData[0])."`";
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have added i simple query to my question showing the way i insert. i don't think i understand you answer to well. does it mean the headers in the excel file need to match the headers in the database? my problem is in the excel sheet i have there is information i don't want so name and age could be in column 1+2 and address can be in column 15. this can change so next week name and age will be in column 3+5 and address at column 17. so was hoping to search for headers to get the right columns.

Comment: @StefanAyresQuinn You can dynamically re-order the columns.  Do my additions help you?

Comment: does this not mean $header will have the headers from the database and I will still have to match $col to the wanted column in the excel file. sorry for this. I do not understand this much.

Comment: @StefanAyresQuinn You match the $header to the incoming data.  Your excel spreadsheet should have a header row for you to read to populate $header

Comment: I done some more research and was able to try your method on my code. from my lack of knowledge with this i was unable to get it to work the way i want. thank you for your input it will come in handy in the future.

Comment: @StefanAyresQuinn   If you had headers in the first row you could try this  $header=join(",",  trim($rowData[0]);